# typescript using the same variable after declare

Tags: typescript

how can I do following code in typescript like python?

```
let startDay: Date = new Date();
let startDay: string = `${startDay.toLocaleDateString('en-US')}`
```

?
or I have to declare two different variable for type convention?

Comment: The `${...}` is unnecessary here, you could just write `startDay.toLocaleDateString('en-US')` since that returns a string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Yo cannot declare the same variable twice in the same context. Javascript or Typescript will not let you do it. Furthermore, Typescript does not allow type mutation so if you use a Date type first, it cannot be changed.

If you don’t need to use the Date version just omit its declaration:

```
let startDay: string = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US');
```